# how to get Category description after product listing

Tags: magento-1.9, category

How can i get category description after product list in product listing page?

Comment: `this did not work for magento 1.9 when you put the code at the bottom of the page at base/default/template/category/vieuw.html and your theme/theme/category/vieuw.html than it stil shows up on your page so does anybody have the good clear solution??` behalf of BG media

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The category description is already displayed in the category view page.
You just need to move elements around.
The template you need to modify is this:
`app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/category/view.phtml`.
take this code:

```
<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-description std">
        <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and move it at the bottom of the file. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

hi you can description of category at any position of product by using registry variable

```
if(Mage::registry('current_category')){
<?php 
$_helper=Mage::helper('catalog/output');
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
if($_description=(Mage::registry('current_category')->getDescription()): ?>
<div class="category-description std">
<?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect exactly...Please be clear in your question.

Go to admin system->configuration->developer and change currentcofigurationscopre option and then in Debug tag `Template Path Hints`,`Add Block Names to Hints' to`yes` and save it.

Then see the block and template location of your layout and do what ever you want in the file.(by this way you can find the file location)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I am just putting the comment to find location of the template file then he can change or add he needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` at the bottom

`echo Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription();`