# Move Category Description to the bottom after product list Magento 2.0.4

Tags: magento2, category, blocks

How can I move Category Description to the bottom after product list in Magento 2.0.4?

I have followed every single advice on this URL:
[how to get Category description after product listing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40335/how-to-get-category-description-after-product-listing)
[how to get Category description to the bottom of the page magento 1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84185/how-to-get-category-description-to-the-bottom-of-the-page-magento-1-9)

But, They don't work because the advice is for Magento 1.9 and not for Magento 2.0.4.

I have tried to modify `list.phtml` but it seems there is another file that is controlling the category image and description feed. Please help.

Answer (score 16):

In your theme folder, add a `catalog_category_view.xml` layout under `Magento_Catalog/layout` (the complete path should be `app/design/frontend/[Company]/[theme_name]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`).

Now you can simply move the description to the bottom with the following:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="category.description" destination="content.bottom" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2):

At category page, **magento call a registry** `current_category` whuch contain the current category object .

If you call this *registry variable* at `list.phtml` then you can ***easily get*** *category description*

---

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category=$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
if($category){
    echo $category->getDescription();
}
```